# problem getting the immediate few rows of a particular row in a HTML table using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater, validation

I am using nested repeaters in my asp.net website.Using these repeaters I am displaying a list of products in tablular form(table is placed in the outer repeater). In the outer(top level) repeater I have the main products and in the inner repeater I have some options associated with the product in the outer repeater(if there are any).While placing an order user is allowed to choose only 2 of the options associated with any product.In order to do this validation I am using a custom validator with the following client side js function.

```
function CountChosenAdditionalOptions(source, arguments) {

        $('table.productslist tbody tr.productTextAlign').each(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $('table. productslist tbody tr.additionalOptions').each(function () {
                var chooseAdditionalOptionsCheckBoxtd = $(this).children("td.chooseOptionCheckBox");
                var additionalOptionChosen = $(chooseAdditionalOptionsCheckBoxtd).children("input[type=checkbox]")[0].checked;
                if (additionalOptionChosen) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            });
            if (count > 2) {
                arguments.IsValid = false;
                return false;
            }
        });       
    }
```

And the sample HTML rendered by the repeaters is as follows

```
<table class= “productslist”>
<tbody>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr class=”productTextAlign”>
.....
.....
</tr>
<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>
<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>
<tr>...</tr>

<tr class=”productTextAlign”></tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The idea behind the validation is to iterate through the outer repeater and for each item in it check the number of options selected in the inner repeater.But as the repeaters are simply rendered as table, with js function as above for each product row it is trying to find the additional option row and incrementing the count irrespective of whether the additional option row is associated with that particular product or not.

Could some one please help in updating the js function to identify the options associated with a particular product and increment the count indicating the number of options chosen?

**Update:**

```
function CountChosenAdditionalOptions(source, arguments) {

        $('table.productslist tbody tr.productTextAlign').each(function () {
            var count = 0; $(this).nextUntil("tr.productTextAlign").each(function () {
                var chooseAdditionalOptionsCheckBoxtd = $(this).children("td.chooseOptionCheckBox");
                var additionalOptionChosen = $(chooseAdditionalOptionsCheckBoxtd).children("input[type=checkbox]")[0].checked;
                if (additionalOptionChosen) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            });
            if (count > 2) {
                arguments.IsValid = false;
                return false;
            }
        });       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `nextUntil`.

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

```
$('table.productslist tbody tr.productTextAlign').each(function () {

    $(this).nextUntil("tr.productTextAlign").each(function () {

    }
}
```

The 2nd loop will run for every row starting after the current `productTextAlign` and continuing until it finds another `productTextAlign`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply.I tried using nextUntil and it works fine.But the problem now is jumping out of .each nested loops immediately when the count is > 2.Using 'return false' does jump out of loop but my serverside control(custom validator) which invokes the js function does not recognise that count is >2. I tried using 'break' instead of 'return false' but I see 'Can't use break out of the loop' warning.Could you please help me this?I am not sure if there is any other way to jump out of the loops in jquery and I think it is complex to implement this in javascript instead of jquery

Comment: I posted the latest js function as an update to my original question above.

Comment: Returning false within an each will break the loop, and not return false from the overall function.  If you want to do that, you will need to set a flag in the loop before breaking, then check the flag on the outside of the each.